# Print a PDF of specified sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of sheet names in the workbook that I want to print to a pdf.
This list starts in cell e13 on the "Print Packages" sheet of the workbook and proceeds vertically, (next sheet name in e14, and e15, and so on).
My code attaches the Print Packages sheet to the pdf it prints out, which I do not want.

Is there is a solution or more efficient way?

```vb
Sub Print_Investor_Summary()
    Save_PDF
End Sub

Function Save_PDF() As Boolean
    Dim Thissheet As String, ThisFile As String, PathName As String
    Dim SvAs As String
    Dim MyName As String ' Added variable declaration for MyName
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' Added variable declaration for the worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print Packages") ' Change "Print Packages" to the actual sheet name
    
    MyName = Range("C3").Value & " Summary"
    SvAs = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MyName & ".pdf" ' Updated the file save name with the full path
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 13 Then lastRow = 13               ' Set the minimum lastRow value to 13
    
    Dim mySheets1() As Variant
    ReDim mySheets1(1 To lastRow - 12)             ' Adjust the array size based on the number of values
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 13 To lastRow                          ' Start from row 13 in Column E
        mySheets1(i - 12) = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value ' Add the value to the array
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sheetName As Variant
Dim sheetNames As String

' Concatenate the contents of mySheets1 into a string
For Each sheetName In mySheets1
    sheetNames = sheetNames & sheetName & vbCrLf
Next sheetName

' Display the contents of mySheets1 in a message box
MsgBox "mySheets1 contains:" & vbCrLf & sheetNames

    ' Select and activate the necessary worksheets
    For Each sheet In mySheets1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Select False
    Next sheet
    
    ' Set Print Quality
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error GoTo SaveError

Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In mySheets1
    Set currentSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet)
    If currentSheet.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        currentSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=SvAs, Quality:=xlQualityMaximum, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    End If
Next sheet

On Error GoTo 0
    
    Save_PDF = True ' Return True to indicate successful execution
    
    ' Open the PDF file on the user's computer
    On Error Resume Next
    Shell "explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & SvAs & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets("Print Packages").Select

EndMacro:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Added to re-enable display alerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Added to re-enable screen updating
    Exit Function

SaveError:
    MsgBox "Unable to save as PDF. Please check your file path and try again."
    Save_PDF = False ' Return False to indicate error
    
    Resume EndMacro ' Go to EndMacro label to enable re-enabling display alerts and screen updating

End Function
```

I tried forcibly excluding it from the variant that contains the names of the sheets.

I have a portion of the code to display the names of the sheets in `mysheets1` that shows that the active sheet is not part of the array.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Select False` *adds the worksheet `sheet` to the current sheet selection*.  You need to use `True` for the first sheet, so it *replaces* the current sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams If i try to do so, it only prints the last sheet in the list, for example, the sheet with its name on e15 if the list is 3 names long. Edit: Oh so I should just use true for sheet 1 and then false for the rest?

Comment: Are you printing all selected sheets into a single PDF?  That looks like what you're doing, but then you have a loop `For Each sheet In mySheets1` to print individual sheets...

Comment: Sorry I am not very good at this, that is in fact what im trying to do, I figured the loop would work to individually add them all together by creating an array that contained all of the names? Ive gone down quite the rabbit hole I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Select False` *adds the worksheet `sheet` to the current sheet selection*. You need to use `True` for the first sheet, so it *replaces* the current sheet.

```
Function Save_PDF() As Boolean
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, replacePrevious As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print Packages")
        Set rng = .Range("E13:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row)
        replacePrevious = True  'first sheet repalces whatever is selected
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(c.Value)
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.PageSetup.PrintQuality = 600
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
            ws.Select replacePrevious 'select the sheet
            'switch to adding the sheet to the already-selected sheet(s)
            replacePrevious = False
        Next c
    End With
    
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
       Filename:= "yourFilePathHere", Quality:= xlQualityStandard, _
       IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
       OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Function
```